# Android / Java Multithreading - Thread doesn't continue until main thread done its work

Tags: java, javascript, android, multithreading, webview

The title might seem kind of vague, but I can't think of another one, so I hope I can make my problem clear:

I'm using an Android WebView and a JavascriptInterface. Communication from my app (Java) towards the WebView (JavaScript) is done like so:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:function()");
```

This is an asynchronous call and should be handled afterwards by the JavaBridge-Thread.

The other way (Javascript towards Java) works bei calling my JavascriptInterface `mainInterface` from my Javascript code. I can call Java methods declared with `@JavascriptInterface` in my JavascriptInterface.
This call is also executed by the JavaBridge-Thread.

Before going into more detail, here are the important codes:

*ModelActivity.java*

```
public boolean loadPropertyIntoWebview(final String element, final String property, final String value){
    final int requestId = jsCallIndex.incrementAndGet();
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:setProperty('"+element+"', '"+property.toLowerCase()+"', '"+value+"', "+requestId+")");

    return waitForJsReturnValue(requestId, 1000);
}

private boolean waitForJsReturnValue(int index, int timeout){
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(true){
        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        if(elapsed > timeout){
            System.out.println("JS RESPONSE TIMEOUT");
            break;
        }

        synchronized (jsReturnValueLock) {
            String value = jsReturnValues.remove(index);

            if(value != null){
                if(value.toLowerCase().equals("true")){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("JS BAD RESPONSE");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            long toWait = timeout - (System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
            if (toWait > 0)
                try {
                    System.out.println("WAIT NOW FOR "+toWait+" ms on index "+index);
                    jsReturnValueLock.wait(toWait);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            else{
                System.out.println("JS RESPONSE TIMEOUT");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void processJsReturnValue(int index, String value){
    System.out.println("RECEIVED ANSWER "+value+" for index "+index+" WAIT FOR UNLOCK");
    synchronized (jsReturnValueLock) {
        System.out.println("UNLOCKED FOR INDEX "+index);
        jsReturnValues.put(index, value);
        jsReturnValueLock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```

*JavascriptInterface.java*

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void onClick(String elementId, String property, String value){
    final String[] info = elementId.split("_");

    dbHandler.addOrUpdateOutVariable(Integer.parseInt(info[0]), Integer.parseInt(info[1]), property, value);

    ((ModelActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            actionManager.fireClickEvent(Integer.valueOf(info[0]), Integer.valueOf(info[1]));
        }
    });
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void processJsReturnValue(String index, String value){
    try{
        ((ModelActivity)context).processJsReturnValue(Integer.parseInt(index), value);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
}
```

What I basically want to do, is get a return value from my JavaScript function `setProperty()` (ModelActivity -> loadPropertyIntoWebview).

During initialization the method `loadPropertyIntoWebview()` is called multiple times from the Main-Thread, and always receives an answer from the JavaBridge-Thread via both `processJsReturnValue()` functions.

The other case, which won't work, is when the user pushes a button in my webview, and invokes

`onClick(String elementId, String property, String value)`

in my JavascriptInterface. The function call

`actionManager.fireClickEvent(Integer.valueOf(info[0]), Integer.valueOf(info[1]));`

goes through several classes and functions which I can't explain in detail, but in last instance it will call

`loadPropertyIntoWebview(final String element, final String property, final String value)`.

This call also comes from the main-Thread, because I explicitly said so in my onClick function:

```
((ModelActivity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        actionManager.fireClickEvent(Integer.valueOf(info[0]), Integer.valueOf(info[1]));
    }
});
```

Debugging revealed the following:

During initilization and after calling

`webview.loadUrl("javascript:setProperty('"+element+"', '"+property.toLowerCase()+"', '"+value+"', "+requestId+")");`

the JavaBridge-Thread immediatley  returns into `processJsReturnValue()`.

When invoked through the user it won't do that. Then it won't go there until the main thread is done with my timedout while(true) loop.

I hope this whole thing isn't too confusing, and someone understands my problem and even has an idea on what's going wrong here.

Comment: How loadPropertyIntoWebview comes from actionManager.fireClickEvent? It sounds like there is a solution to what you are asking but I don't understand what code is processed by both of the threads(Main and JavaBridge) and why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate onClick and processJsReturnValue as two different JavascriptInterface classes, create their instances and register them independently. Not sure but seems like now they block each other.

Comment: That actually sounds like it might work. Unfortunately I just got out a meeting where we decided that we don't need the return value necessarily. But I'll keep that in mind in case we need a return value any other place. I might even try it nonetheless, because I want to know whether that would have solved my problem.